# What does this script mean?

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to understand the following shell script:

```
/usr/local/bin/uncrustify -q -c ~/objc.cfg -l oc
```

But I don't know what some of the parts say. This part

```
/usr/local/bin/uncrustify
```

says go to the bin directory and run the program uncrustify with two parameters -q and -c.

This part

```
~/objc.cfg -l oc
```

Says look in the home directory for the file objc.cfg and pass it in as a parameter too. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a script but simply a command. `-q`, `-c`, `~/objc.cfg`, `-l` and `oc` are all parameters of `/usr/local/bin/uncrustify`. For its semantic take a look at `man uncrustify`. Also `/usr/local/bin/` is not needed as it's likely to be in your `$PATH` environment variable, so:

```
uncrustify -q -c ~/objc.cfg -l oc
```

behaves the same.

---

From `man uncrustify`:

- `-q` : Quiet mode - no output on stderr;
- `-c ~/objc.cfg` : Use the config file `~/objc.cfg`;
- `-l oc` : Language override: OC.